# Mathematica - Force Logarithmic Scale on Plots & Grouped Axes Labels

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I have a `ListPointPlot3D` plot and all three axes contain a logarithmic distribution of data points.

Like this:

```
..... .  .    .        .                .                                .
```

How do I force Mathematica to make the axes' scales logarithmic so that I get a linear distribution of data points across them?

Thanks

Comment: Because of their lack of visual cues I find 3D point plots quite often pointless (pun intended). Look at my plot below; can you visually assess the coordinates of each point? You'd need sticks or shadows or so to make it more interpretable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't a LogLogLogPlot, so the next best thing would be to take the logs of your data and plot those. You then have to come up with `Ticks` of your own.

A rough version:

```
tks = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000};
list = 10^RandomReal[{0, 4}, {100, 3}]

ListPointPlot3D[Log[10, list]}, 
   Ticks ->
    {
      {Log[10, tks], tks}\[Transpose],
      {Log[10, tks], tks}\[Transpose],
      {Log[10, tks], tks}\[Transpose]
    }, 
    BoxRatios -> 1, PlotStyle -> PointSize -> 0.02
]
```

[image]

`Ticks` has many more possibilities to beautify your scale. I trust you'll find your way to its [location in the manual](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html).

Comment: I can't find it in the documentation right now (and I should be doing my real work), but isn't there an option since version 8 that allows more generic rescaling of axis scales?

Comment: @Verbeia `ScalingFunctions` only works for the Chart range (BubbleChart, Histogram, BarChart...). Alas, not for the Plot family.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to redo your plot as a `BubbleChart3D` (with constant bubble sizes, I guess), you can use the `ScalingFunctions` ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScalingFunctions.html)) option to rescale the axes to log form. It can also be used to scale axes in ways other than log-scale. Since you are using `ListPointPlot3D`, you might need to rearrange your input data as well.

This is one of the annoying distinctions between "charting" and "plotting" in Mathematica. As far as I know, the `ScalingFunction` option only applies to "charts" (financial, bar and bubble charts), not plots like `ListPlot` or `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: Although `ScalingFunctions` is listed in the `BubbleChart3D` doc page (though suspiciously not as a clickable hyperlink like the other options)  and `BubbleChart` is mentioned on the `ScalingFunctions` page, this option does NOT appear to work for `BubbleChart3D`. The syntax coloring colors it red and you get an error message " BubbleChart3D::optx: "Unknown option \!\(ScalingFunctions -> {\"Log\", \"Log\", \"Log\", None}\) in ... "

Comment: Interesting! (And another case where I should wait till I get home and actually check something works before answering). I suppose I should delete this answer, then?

Comment: It's a new option that works fine in many other situations. I'd leave it here for now. Perhaps one of the WRI members of this platform might have something to say about this.

Comment: @Verbeia, thanks but `ScalingFunctions` isn't a recognised option for my version of Mathematica (8.0.1.0)